# CSS\JS\JQuery: Customize color of clicked (not chosen) option in multiselect box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a multiselect box, and want to change the default blue color that marks options I click.

The closest I got was to have the blue when I click, and then when I click on another option (the blue moves to the newer click) - a perminent red appears as backgroung on passed clicked option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $().ready(function() {
      $("select").change(function () {
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
              $(this).css('backgroundColor','red');
          });
       })
       .trigger('change');
   });
</script>
```

BUT this is not specificaly what I need... Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I don’t believe that you can achieve this effect and definitely not with cross browser support. I'd recommend having a look at some of the jQuery form "theming" plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Styling native forms element will cause you serious headaches.

You could try using this jquery plugin: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/ which provides nice enhancement for multi-select boxes form elements.

d.